# How to capture only part of regex

Tags: python

I would like to extract 'HD' or 'SD' from the below string, yet it is returning the entire search match instead of just those two letters. How would I just get 'SD' or 'HD' ?

```
re.search(r';Video=([A-Z]{2})', 'nt;Video=SD-H.264;D').group()
';Video=SD'
```

Comment: Use the capture group. Try `group(1)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify which group to return:

```
>>> re.search(r';Video=([A-Z]{2})', 'nt;Video=SD-H.264;D').group(1)
'SD'
```